# How to make the Eclipse Android layout editor expand in height?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I've been playing around with Android lately and I've run into a problem building UIs. More precisely, I'm pretty sure when I was building the first layout, the layout editor in Eclipse adjusted the visible area so when I added new widgets, it stretched in height to display them.

Now I have a problem that whenever the widgets fill the area, it's impossible for me to properly lay them out since the preview window displays only the height of a single screen, even if it's a simple LinearLayout with a bunch of textviews to fill about 2 screen heights.

Also, I'm using the latest stable Eclipse and ADT plugin, target platform is 2.2.

**EDIT**

What I meant was that the editor doesn't display the elements that don't fit inside a single screen height and clips the stuff (see the image to see how it clips, there are actually 2 more textviews that are clipped totally) which makes impossible to build UIs that are taller that a single screen height.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal there is a clipping occuring. I just tested it on my eclipse and I have the same behavior than you.

If what you want to achieve is creating a layout bigger than your screen size, you should use scroll views (and insert your initial layout in it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
isScrollContainer="true" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/exampleView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
...
```

Once in scroll mode, the layout will auto adjust.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it was probably obvious, but I couldn't find anything by googling. I will award you the bonus too, as soon as it's available (about 22hours).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[image]

Hope this helps. If this hasn't solved your problem, then please explain your question again in different words, because that's how I understood it.

Comment: Edited the original post with a better explanation.

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse and clean the project. Eclipse can be quite loony sometimes.

Comment: Tried that, tried creating a project from scratch, tried installing older versions of everything and also set up a separate environment on another computer, but nothing worked. So it's either really-really obvious for me to notice or it's a really complicated problem.